# SomethingBefore $variable - what is that thing before variable?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on some Laravel project based on OOP PHP.

There are often used things like:

```
    public function (Request $request){}
```

What is the word `Request` before variable `$request`? I can't even read about it because don't know how it is called.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: It's called type hinting.  Google it or http://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials/type-hinting

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests

Comment: Reading a manual is a hard job.

Comment: About which variable you talking.. Please clear your Question 1st

Comment: @bassxzero I think this is it. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

These are *type hints* - as you can [read about here in the documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

> Type declarations allow functions to require that parameters are of a certain type at call time. If the given value is of the incorrect type, then an error is generated: in PHP 5, this will be a recoverable fatal error, while PHP 7 will throw a TypeError exception.
>
> To specify a type declaration, the type name should be added before the parameter name. The declaration can be made to accept NULL values if the default value of the parameter is set to NULL.

In your case (I've rewritten it a little...)

```
public function foo(Request $request){}
```

This is telling the `foo()` function that `$request` must be an instance of `Request`.

Answer (score 1):

That is type hinting `Request` is a Class. By referencing it before the variable you force PHP in only requesting instance of `Request` to be passed to this method.

If you pass an `string` or other type to this method it will throw an Error.

I suggest you look do a quick google search on OOP in PHP for beginners or have a look at [Laracasts](http://laracasts.com) it has some great resources to getting started with the Laravel Framework